# How to write Column names (C1, C2, C3) below each column?

Tags: matrices

**We can write Row names (R1, R2, R3) in each row**

> How to write Column names (C1, C2, C3) below each column?

```
\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
A &=
\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\rowcolor{orange!15}
y+k & y & y \\
y & y+k & y \\
y & y & y+k \\
\end{array}
\right|
\begin{array}{l}
R_1\\
R_2\\
R_3
\end{array}\\ \\
%
&=
\left|\begin{array}{c>{\columncolor{red!25}}cc}
y+k & y & y \\
y & y+k & y \\
y & y & y+k \\
\end{array}
\right|
\begin{array}{l}
%\rowcolor{yellow!15}
C_1\\
C_2\\
C_3
\end{array}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use `blkarray`, as in your previous question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your setup of a stacked equation containing matrices, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{align*}
    A &= \left| \begin{array}{ c c c }
      \rowcolor{orange!15}
      y + k &   y   &   y   \\
        y   & y + k &   y   \\
        y   &   y   & y + k
    \end{array}\right|
    \begin{array}{ l }
      R_1 \\
      R_2 \\
      R_3
    \end{array} \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    &= \begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      \\
      \left|\begin{array}{ c >{\columncolor{red!25}}c c }
        \eqmakebox[L]{$y + k$} &   y   &   y   \\
          y   & \eqmakebox[C]{$y + k$} &   y   \\
          y   &   y   & \eqmakebox[R]{$y + k$}
      \end{array}\right| \\
      \eqmakebox[L]{$C_1$}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}\eqmakebox[C]{$C_2$}\hspace{2\arraycolsep}\eqmakebox[R]{$C_3$}
    \end{array}
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```